# Is it possible to generate html from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to generate html from JavaScript? For example, I have this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    for (i=0; i<=length; i++)
      {
        //I want to display a <p> tag containing the value of i
      }  
    </script>
```

So the generated html should look something like this if length = 5:

```
    <p>0</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
```

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very possible. You would insert the elements into the DOM:

```
var NewP;
var Text;

for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    NewP = document.createElement("p"); // Create a p element
    Text = document.createTextNode(i + ""); // Create text to go inside with string value of i
    NewP.appendChild(Text); // Add text to p element
    document.body.appendChild(NewP); // Append newly-created p element to body element in DOM tree
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thanks!!! I'll accept the answer when it allows me to do so.

Comment: If I wanted to create a link instead, how would I add that?

Answer (score 1):

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--
greeting = "<H1>Hi Web surfers!</H1>"
welcome = "<P>Welcome to <CITE>stackoverflow.com</CITE>.</P>"
// -->
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--
document.write(greeting)
document.write(welcome)
// -->
</SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Your code would look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var total = 5;
for (i=0; i <= total; i++)
  {
    document.write('<p>' + i + '</p>');
  }  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's possible. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var html = "";
  for (i=0; i<=6; i++) {
      html += "<p>" + i + "</p>";
  } 
  document.write(html);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put 
`document.write('<p>' + i + '</p>');` in your loop

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/HTML/GeneratingHTMLOntheFly.htm

but there are some nice plugins that facilitate the process better, specially if you intend to do more of this:

http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/

http://akdubya.github.com/dustjs/

Answer (score -2):

You can make a `<div id="div"></div>`in your html and simply in the function:

```
$("#div").html('<p>'+i+'</p>');
```